# Random 2x2 tables with fixed margin totals in Julia

Tags: random, julia

Is there a way to generate a random 2x2 table with fixed margin totals (as with using `r2dtable` in R)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to sample only from 2x2 tables and assume that all admissible matrices are equally probable then you can use something like:

```
function rand2x2(r1::Integer, r2::Integer, c1::Integer, c2::Integer)
    if min(r1, r2, c1, c2) < 0 || r1+r2 != c1+c2
        error("invalid parameters")
    end
    a11 = rand(max(0, c1-r2):min(r1, c1))
    [a11 r1-a11; c1-a11 r2-c1+a11]
end
```

where `r1` and `r2` are row margins and `c1` and `c2` are column margins.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the R implementation, perhaps the following:

```
function r2dtable(r::Tuple{Int,Int},c::Tuple{Int,Int})
    sum(r)==sum(c) || error("Rows and columns must sum to same number")
    min(r...,c...)>=0 || error("Input should be non-negative margins")
    rswap = indmin(r)==2
    cswap = indmin(c)==2
    r2 = minmax(r...)
    c2 = minmax(c...)
    rowismin = indmin((r2,c2))==1
    swapmat = [0 1 ; 1 0]
    cycle = rand(0:(rowismin ? r2[1] : c2[1]))
    base = rowismin ? 
      [r2[1]-cycle 0+cycle ; c2[2]-r2[1]+cycle c2[1]-cycle] :
      [c2[1]-cycle r2[2]-c2[1]+cycle  ; 0+cycle r2[1]-cycle]
    return (swapmat^xor(rswap,!rowismin))*base*(swapmat^xor(cswap,rowismin))
end
```

is what you mean. You can use it for example, as follows:

```
julia> srand(2);

julia> r2dtable((2,2),(2,2))
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1
 1  1

julia> r2dtable((2,2),(2,2))
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  2
 2  0

julia> r2dtable((2,2),(2,2))
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  0
 0  2
```

(this may contain bugs, so be sure to check it and perhaps fix them ;))

Comment: A Fortran version of R's r2dtable version that does not have licensing issues is presented here: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2346669